# How to provide List<int> for a data theory ? "InlineData"

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

How to provide List as a data source for a data theory, I can't find anything in InlineData that supports this :

```
    [InlineData(null, new[] { 42, 2112 }, null)] // This doesn't work, I need something that works with List<int>
    [Trait("Category", "API")]
    [Trait("Category", "Partner")]
    [Trait("Category", "Smoke")]
    public void VerifyGetCarListAsync(int? colorID, List<int> carIDs, int? sellerID){//}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This cannot be accomplished with `InlineData` you can only do this with `MemberData`, `PropertyData` or `ClassData` see the `MemberData` example below.

```
[MemberData(nameof(Data))]
public void VerifyGetCarListAsync(int? colorID, List<int> carIDs, int? sellerID){
    // test code
}


public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data(){
    yield return new object[] { null, new List<int>{ 42, 2112 }, null };
    yield return new object[] { 1, new List<int>{ 43, 2112 }, null };
    yield return new object[] { null, new List<int>{ 44, 2112 }, 6 };
}
```

Comment: "=> {" does not compile

Comment: public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data =>
        new List<object[]>
        {
            new object[] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new object[] { -4, -6, -10 },
            new object[] { -2, 2, 0 },
            new object[] { int.MinValue, -1, int.MaxValue },
        };

Comment: You could do

`[Theory]
[InlineData(null, new[] { 42, 2112 }, null)]
public void VerifyGetCarListAsync(int? colorID, int[] carIDs, int? sellerID)
{
    var carIDList = carIDs.ToList();
}`

Comment: `PropertyData` has been renamed to `MemberData`. https://xunit.net/docs/upgrade-extensions